# How to get a list of supported region formats in Windows 7 and Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, regional-settings

Is there a way to get a list of supported region formats in Windows 7 and Windows 10? It's the list shown in the dropdown indicated in the dialog below:

[image]

Ideally I'm looking for a plain text file output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there a way to get a list of supported region formats

Use the following PowerShell command:

```
[System.Globalization.Cultureinfo]::GetCultures("AllCultures").DisplayName | sort > languages.txt
```

Example:

```
> [System.Globalization.Cultureinfo]::GetCultures("AllCultures").DisplayName | sort > languages.txt
> type languages.txt
Afrikaans
Afrikaans (South Africa)
Albanian
Albanian (Albania)
Alsatian
Alsatian (France)
Amharic
Amharic (Ethiopia)
Arabic
Arabic (Algeria)
Arabic (Bahrain)
Arabic (Egypt)
Arabic (Iraq)
Arabic (Jordan)
Arabic (Kuwait)
Arabic (Lebanon)
Arabic (Libya)
Arabic (Morocco)
Arabic (Oman)
Arabic (Qatar)
Arabic (Saudi Arabia)
Arabic (Syria)
Arabic (Tunisia)
Arabic (U.A.E.)
Arabic (Yemen)
Armenian
Armenian (Armenia)
Assamese
Assamese (India)
Azeri
Azeri (Cyrillic)
Azeri (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan)
...
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [Getting a list of Windows Language Locales with Windows Powershell](https://powershell.org/2013/04/15/getting-a-list-of-windows-language-locales-with-windows-powershell/)